# Javascript convert time to get different between windows and linux

Tags: datetime

I converted time value at client side, when I tested it from same browser:chrome on linux and windows.

windows:

```
    var d = new Date(1995,9,1,1,15,0,0) 
    d
    Sun Oct 01 1995 01:15:00 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
    d.getTime()
    **812463300000**
    var d = new Date(1995,9,1,3,15,0,0) 
    d
    Sun Oct 01 1995 03:15:00 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
    d.getTime()
    **812470500000**
```

linux :

```
 var d = new Date(1995,9,1,1,15,0,0) 
   d
   Sun Oct 01 1995 01:15:00 GMT+1200 (NZST)
   d.getTime()
   **812466900000**
   var d = new Date(1995,9,1,3,15,0,0) 
   d
   Sun Oct 01 1995 03:15:00 GMT+1300 (NZDT)
   d.getTime()
   **812470500000**
```

The problem is the server which installed at same linux pc will get different milliseconds value which I convert at client side, the next step is the server convert the value with server timezone to string value.

I know it should be resolved by converting the string value at server side, but if I must convert it at client side, anyone can give me a correct direction to resolve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't depend on the client (end user) clock -- get the time on the server as you said.
Always use GMT / UTC and only convert it to a local time when you're displaying it to a person.

Answer (score 0):

The date:

```
var d = new Date(1995,9,1,1,15,0,0)
```

will be converted to a local time using the current system settings. To make everything consistent, send the **UTC** time since epoch from the server and convert that, e.g.:

```
new Date(812463300000); // Sat Sep 30 22:15:00 UTC+1000 1995
```

will create a date object for exactly the same instant regardless of where the server is located or what the system settings are.